# Is rollback needed after Hibernate exception if clear is used instead

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, rollback

if I have a Hibernate exception during a call to commit. In the catch block, is rollback necessary if clear is used instead?

e.g.

```
EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
t.begin();
try {
    ...
    t.commit();
} catch (StaleObjectStateException ex) {
    ... // rollback needed?
} finally {
    t.clear();
}
```

instead of

```
EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
t.begin();
try {
    ...
    t.commit();
} catch (StaleObjectStateException ex) {
    if (t.isActive()) {
        t.rollback();
    }
}
```

What are the differences and how would you make your decision on using which?

Thank you

Comment: rollback should go on catch, not on finally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a hibernate exception occurs Hibernate itself does a rollback in that session. That means no `t.rollback()` is necessary in the catch statement.

Event more, when a hibernate exception occurs, the session instance is broken and must not be used any more. If you continue to use this instance, then you'll get a StaleStateException. Instead of the clear() you must create a new session instance.